# I'm trying to render a MP4 with these settings but it doesn't work

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

> ffmpeg -i Power_1080p.mp4 cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0
>   analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1
>   me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11
>   fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=1 lookahead_threads=1
>   sliced_threads=0 slices=2 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0
>   constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1
>   weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=25 keyint_min=13 scenecut=40
>   intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=25 rc=2pass mbtree=1 bitrate=4000
>   ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=51 qpstep=4 cplxblur=20.0
>   qblur=0.5 vbv_maxrate=4000 vbv_bufsize=4000 nal_hrd=none filler=0
>   ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00 Power_TEST_1080p.mp4

Hi guys, I'm trying to render a MP4 with these settings and I get

```
[NULL @ 063b0b00] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'cabac=1'
cabac=1: Invalid argument
```

as an error. I need to render the MP4 with these settings (I **DON'T** want to use anything else)

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

All of the settings soup after the filename are private options of the x264 encoder, for which you need to pass them as a string to a private option, delimited by `:`.
e.g.

```
-x264opts "cabac=1:ref=3:me=hex"
```

Many of the options are univalent so you can input them as seen above, but a few are multivalent (like deblock) and some don't correspond to input parameters like `analyze`, which is set by `partitions`. For these, see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MeGUI/x264_Settings for a description of parameters.

Comment: What program can I use for using these options?

Comment: ffmpeg with libx264 enabled.